# Relative positions in permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Say we have the following string: $$\text{s=aaaabbcdefghijkl} \tag{1}$$

- a) In how many ways can we permute $s$ ($|s|=16$) such that all $4$ a's are spaced by at least 3 spaces relative to another (To clarify: it is sufficient in one direction, e.g. axxxaxaxxxa... each a has at least one other a 3 steps away): (More examples at the bottom).
  $$\text{s'=abbcadefaghiajkl}$$
  Or
  $$\text{s''=abbcadefghiajkla}$$

For case a), my initial guess was that once the first a is placed, the remaining ones have only 1 possibility. So to place the first a we have 13 choices (the 3 extra a's put aside for now), thus overall we have: (notation $n_x$ is used to denote the number x's we have) $$\dbinom{13}{1}\dbinom{12}{n_b}\dbinom{12-n_b}{n_c}\dots \dbinom{1}{1}$$

From the comments, I now realise my attempt above is wrong, since I did not take into account the relation between possible triple-spacing allowed within the size of s.

- b) More generally how is the counting done if $s$ has length $k$ and we only require at most $n$ $(n=0,1,...,n_a)$ of the $n_a$ $a$'s to be spaced by $3$ places, and the remaining ones are free to take any place? In other words, e.g. for case $n=1,$ at most $1$ $a$ can be found that has another $a$ 3 spaces away from itself, thus for $n=1$ one such setup of s would be $\text{aaaiabcb}\dots$ (only the first and last one are spaced by 3 from one another, thus n=1 satisfied.)
- If you find the general case is not obvious to solve for, feel free to consider the case b) for example (1).

*For simplicity assume s has enough letters other than a's that the case of all a's being $n=m$ can always take place.*

### If **tldr**,

- The main question is: How to count the number of ways $s$ can be permuted such that *at most* $n$ $a$'s see  (either to left or right) another $a$ 3 steps from themselves? (*where $n=1,2,\dots, n_a$*)

---

Further examples for case a): axxxaxaxxxaxxxxx, axxxaxxxaxxxaxxx, xaxxxaxxxaxxxaxx, xxaxxxaxxxaxxxax, xxxaxxxaxxxaxxxa, axxxaxxxxxxaxxxa, xaxxxaxxxxxaxxxa, ... (letters other than a replaced by x here for clarity).

Comment: You don't have 13 choices for the positions of the $a$s.

Comment: I realize, but there are still only four possible ways to place the $a$s.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh... I was really wrong there then. I mean the idea is that in case a), that every a must have another a 3 spaces away, so another valid setup in a) would be $\text{abbcadefghiajkla}$ and every a satisfies the condition.

Comment: In agreement with Barak's comment on his now deleted answer, I think you should *definitely* say "by at least 3 spaces" rather than your "by 3 spaces", in the question itself. Your examples show that is the condition.

Comment: @coffeemath It seems like the condition is that for each $a$ there is at least one $a$ on one side that has exactly three letters between them, but that there are not $a$s closer. But the question could be much clearer by laying out where the $a$s could go. As it stands, this question is a mess.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Now it seems that it is only required that each a has at least one other a (on one or the other side of it) with exactly 3 letters between, but that some third a might be closer than 3 steps away to either. See OP example axxxaxaxxxa. And I suppose e.g. aaxaaxxx would count also by the new "rule", In my opinion the OP should clarify all this.

Comment: @coffeemath yes it counts too, in fact in your last example you re covering an instance of case a), since any a in it sees at least another a 3 steps away. With all thr examples i ve given in case a and b and at the bottom, I hope everything s become clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for 4 $a$'s and a string of length $n\ge 6$ and with the latest restriction: Each $a$ must have to its left or its right another $a$ with exactly three letters between (some of these may also be $a$ or not). For more $a$'s the count gets much more complicated.

Now the leftmost $a$ in say position $p$ is required to have another $a$ in position $p+4.$ So we'll call this the "left pair" $(w,x)=(p,p+4).$ Similarly the rightmost $a$ in position say $q$ is required to have another $a$ with exactly three letters between, this is the "right pair" $(y,z)=(q-4,q).$
These pairs chosen, the requirements are automatically satisfied for all 4 $a$'s. To count these we only need worry that we need $x \neq y.$

Now $w$ can be anything from position $p=1$ up to $p=n-5$ (To leave room for the right pair which has rightmost possible position $(n-4,n).$) Similarly the right pair can have its left end anywhere from position $p=2$ up to $p=n-4.$ So as far as the left endpoints of the left and right pairs, we are choosing them from the numbers between $1$ and $n-4$ which means, including unwanted collisions wherein $x=y$ that we have so far $\binom{n-4}{2}$ choices, from which something has to be subtracted.

The bad cases are of the form axxxaxxxa which is a string of length $9$ so there are $n-8$ of these, I think. Anyway we now subtract $n-8$ form the above binomial coefficient to get the total number of ways to place the $a$'s.

Now whatever else makes up the original string can be rearranged in some number $m$ of ways, obtained using a multinomial coeffient, and then this would be multiplied by the count of how many ways to place the $a$'s

Note: The least $n$ for which there is an allowable $a$ placement is $n=6,$ the string being aaxxaa. For $n=6,7$ the "subtracted" $n-8$ above should be viewed as $0$ to reflect that there are no bad strings axxxaxxxa (such a bad string must have length $9$ so won't occur when $n=6,7$ (nor when $n=8$ but in that case the above says to subtract $8-8=0$ anyway).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very interesting approach. 1 or 2 questions if I may:1)why do you exlude the cases axxxaxxxa? Is it due to the way the counting is being performed? 2) the n you have used denotes the length if thr string, the n I had used in the question denoted the *number of a's* that were required to see another a 3 steps away. This said, do you think your approach can be extended to cover the latter case? (i.e. when not all a's have to satisfy the condition but only n of them)

Comment: As for 1): If one had axxxaxxxa where the first a was the leftmost a of the string and the last a was the rightmost a of the string, there would be no place remaining in the string to place the fourth a... it would have to go somewhere after the first a and before the last in the axxxaxxxa string, but no positions of the x's here are exactly 3 away from an a. For 2) I don't see any clear way to count in general, and it seems hard to even set up. How does one count the number of a's which are 3 away from another a? If the "remaining a's can be anywhere" some might end up also 3 away from an a.

Comment: How can it be that your expression is independent of the number a's? (If i understood correctly the 4 in your binomial coeff comes from 3 steps+1 and not the count of a)

Comment: There *definitely* need to be 4 a's in order for this count to work. $n$ is the length of the string which must be at least 6. So the formula is dependent on there being 4 a's so is in that sense dependent on the number of a's. As I note at the top, I don't see how to generalize to some arbitrary but fixed number of a's, but I have a few ideas about that. (If I get anywhere with a fixed number $k$ of a's I'll add something.)

Comment: Alright, cheers.